# broken packages libpng12-0 when install lsphp71 on ubuntu 16.10

Tags: php, ubuntu, caching, litespeed

After run `wget -O - http://rpms.litespeedtech.com/debian/enable_lst_debain_repo.sh | bash`, when I try to install lsphp71 via `apt install -y lsphp71` on ubuntu 16.10, it gave this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lsphp71 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable
       Recommends: php-readline
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But it has no error when install on ubuntu 16.04.2

I tried to list all apt packages, there are only 8 packages with prefix `libpng`:

```
libpng16-16              libpng++-dev             libpnglite-dev           libpng-sixlegs-java-doc  
libpng-dev               libpnglite0              libpng-sixlegs-java      libpng-tools
```

Package `libpng16-16` is already installed.

How can I install lsphp71? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintained packages for LSPHP are only for Long Term Support releases of Ubuntu. It only supports 12.04, 14.04, and 16.04. If you need LSPHP71 you can either compile it yourself ( Many guides on how to compile PHP on Ubuntu, just make sure you have --with-litespeed flag when compiling. ) or use LiteSpeed Web GUI.

More information can be found here at LiteSpeed's Wiki.
https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:php:lsapi

Comment: BTW even I tried lsphp7.0 on ubuntu 16.04, it's not supported well.